# Setting subreport parameter based on the field value clicked in parent report

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to design a subreport in ssrs 2005 where the subreport's parameter value is set on the field value clicked in the parent report.

For example, the parent report has a column for the department names. If someone clicks on one of the department name values, that value is passed as the parameter to the subreport, and the subreport would then show a graph against that department value.

I have tried creating an action against the department name field and selecting the "go to report" option, selecting subreport's name and passing department field value as parameter but when i run the report and click the field value it opens the child report in a separate window as a separate report.

I am looking for a solution whereby the subreport's graph is refreshed when someone clicks on the department field value of the parent report while parent report staying visible.

Is it something possible?

Answer (score 0):

The following answer and screenshot are based on SSRS 2008. If memory serves me right, it worked in a similar way in SSRS 2005 (the [documentation for SSRS 2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159847%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) implies as much).

Here's the basic steps:

- click on your TextBox with the field, and select the `Action` property
- select the "Go to report" action, specify your subreport
- "Add" a paramter, and pass the field's value to it

Here's a screenshot of the 2008 dialog to set this up:

[image: dialog for subreport with parameter]

Comment: Thanks @Jeroen it works but the only problem with this approach is that the subreport opens up in a separate window showing only the content of the child report and not the parent report. Can we somehow show both parent and child reports together?

Comment: Possibly. You'd need a drilldown reports. However, if you want this you should consider updating your question, and include quite a bit more detail on what you want and also on what you've tried so far (and why it didn't work).